# Azure IoT Remote Monitoring Web UI doesn't start on local machine - Unauthorized

Tags: azure, azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-sdk

I'm trying to get the Azure IoT Remote Monitoring Web UI (https://github.com/Azure/pcs-remote-monitoring-webui) to run on my local machine and connect to a deployed instance of the solution at https://{your solution name}.azurewebsites.net/

I get an error from the server. Can anyone help me?

I'm following this tutorial:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-accelerators/iot-accelerators-remote-monitoring-customize

When I run npm start, I get these messages in the browser console:

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 401 (Unauthorized)

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://{your solution name}.azurewebsites.net//config/v1/solution-settings/theme' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Answer (score 1):

In the Azure Portal, find the resource for the deployed App Service that you are trying to ping (the *.azurewebsites.net address). Under the options for this App Service (in the left hand pane) there should be a CORS option. Once you’ve opened up the CORS option you should be able to whitelist URLs - enter your full localhost URL including the ports and https://. Save the changes and then reload the page that previously wasn’t working - changes might take a few minutes to apply.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That actually worked! However, now I get another message in the console: "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 401 (Unauthorized)". And this message appears in the browser: "Error: You need to login to call the service."

Comment: Did you run the start script with the unsafe flag as per step 5 of [this guide]( https://github.com/Azure/pcs-remote-monitoring-webui/blob/master/src/services/authService.js)? Also check that authEnabled is set to false in your app.config.js file.

Comment: I just re-checked those two things and they are in place. Same results, sorry. Any ideas?